# Merge where definition exists

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have 3 tables I'm working with here. `ATTRIBUTE_MAP`, `GROUP_DEFINITIONS`, and `GROUP_MAP`.

`ATTRIBUTE_MAP` contains the `CUST_ID` and the associated `ATTRIBUTE_ID`.

`GROUP_DEFINITIONS` defines a group. Its columns are `GROUP_ID`, `ATTRIBUTE_1`, `VALUE_1`, `ATTRIBUTE_2`, `VALUE_2`, `ATTRIBUTE_3`, `VALUE_3`  A group consists of 1 to 3 attributes with values.  For example, an attribute could be 'State' with its value being 'New York'.  Values can also be null for boolean values like 'Owns Car'.

`GROUP_MAP` simply maps the `CUST_ID` to a `GROUP_ID`.

Now, I'm trying to write a script that will look at the `ATTRIBUTE_MAP` and see if a customer falls into one of the defined groups in `GROUP_DEFINITIONS`.  If he (the customer) does, then insert/update a row into `GROUP_MAP` with the `CUST_ID` and `GROUP_ID`.  The part I'm having trouble with, is matching the attribute values.

Here is what I have so far:

```
merge GROUP_MAP gm using 
( select am.CUST_ID
        ,am.ATTRIBUTE_ID
        ,am.START_DATE
        ,gd.GROUP_ID
        ,gd.ATTRIBUTE_1
        ,gd.VALUE_1
        ,gd.ATTRIBUTE_2
        ,gd.VALUE_2
        ,gd.ATTRIBUTE_3
        ,gd.VALUE_3
from ATTRIBUTE_MAP am, GROUP_DEFINITIONS gd ) src
on gm.GROUP_ID=src.GROUP_ID 
    AND gm.CUST_ID=src.CUST_ID

when not matched then -- create association in GROUP_MAP
insert (CUST_ID, GROUP_ID, FROM_DATE)
values (src.CUST_ID, src.GROUP_ID, src.START_DATE);
```

Am I approaching this correctly? I'm guessing I need to just improve my nested select statement in my merge to join the `ATTRIBUTE_MAP` and `PEER_GROUP_DEFINTIONS` and then go from there.  Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Here's an example for reference:

`ATTRIBUTE_MAP`:

`+---------+--------------+------------+
| CUST_ID | ATTRIBUTE_ID | VALUE      |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| 50      | 1            | 'New York' |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| 50      | 2            |            |
+---------+--------------+------------+`

`GROUP_DEFINITIONS`:

`+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| GROUP_ID | ATTRIBUTE_1 | VALUE_1    | ATTRIBUTE_2 | VALUE_2 | ATTRIBUTE_3 | VALUE_3 |
+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| 10       | 1           | 'New York' | 2           |         |             |         |
+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+
| 20       | 2           |            |             |         |             |         |
+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------+`

and so the script should generate (in `GROUP_MAP`):

`+---------+----------+--------+
| CUST_ID | GROUP_ID | DATE   |
+---------+----------+--------+
| 50      | 10       | *date* |
+---------+----------+--------+
| 50      | 20       | *date* |
+---------+----------+--------+`

Comment: Could you explain what is the relationship between ATTRIBUTE_MAP and  GROUP_DEFINITIONS

Comment: @KamranFarzami There really is no direct relation between the two.  ATTRIBUTE_MAP maps discrete attributes/values to customers, whereas GROUP_DEFINTIONS is more of like a dimension table - it is only meant to define a group.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Does an ATTRIBUTE_MAP record have to match all of the attributes in a GROUP_DEFINITIONS record, or just any 1 of them? Is an empty GROUP_DEFINITIONS.ATTRIBUTE_[X] value NULL, or is it a blank string?

Comment: and the value for am.START_DATE is that something you need to take into consideration, and what type is it. Is it DATE or DATETIME. The column DATE  within GROUP_MAP is that just a timestamp when the record was inserted into the GROUP_MAP table?

Comment: @radshop An empty attribute is NULL.  An ATTRIBUTE_MAP record only contains an association of 1 customer to 1 attribute.  If there are multiple attributes for a customer, then they are separate records.  A customer will fall into a group if the attributes assigned to him meet all the attribute 'conditions' in a group.

Comment: @KamranFarzami Yes, I do need to take it into account, but I was just ignoring it for now.  It is a DATE.  (There is technically a DATE column in ATTRIBUTE_MAP)

Comment: @Ted how should the code handle this situation? INSERT INTO #GROUP_DEFINITIONS VALUES (30, 1, 'New York', 5, 'Bakery', NULL, NULL)

Comment: @Ted - the community has provided some answers. Any feedback?

Comment: @radshop I'm doing some testing now... I'm having to create a bunch of new test data to make sure the answers work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be totally off, but it looks like your inner select needs to be something like this. If I understand what you are trying to do, this will return a unique list of CUST_ID, GROUP_ID, START_DATE where all of the customer attributes match all of the group attributes. Just wrote this fast, so might have some errors, but it might get you going the right direction.

```
with gd as (
  SELECT GROUP_ID, ATTRIBUTE_1 as ATTRIBUTE_ID, VALUE_1 as VALUE from GROUP_DEFINITIONS 
  UNION
  SELECT GROUP_ID, ATTRIBUTE_2, VALUE_2 from GROUP_DEFINITIONS 
  UNION
  SELECT GROUP_ID, ATTRIBUTE_3, VALUE_3 from GROUP_DEFINITIONS
)
MERGE GROUP_MAP gm
USING
    (
  SELECT am.CUST_ID, gd.GROUP_ID, am.START_DATE
  FROM ATTRIBUTE_MAP am 
  JOIN gd
  ON  am.ATTRIBUTE_ID = gd.ATTRIBUTE_ID  AND coalesce(am.VALUE, '') = coalesce(gd.VALUE, '')
  join (select GROUP_ID, count(*) as ATTR_COUNT from gd where ATTRIBUTE_ID is NOT NULL group by GROUP_ID) as gc
  on gd.GROUP_ID = gc.GROUP_ID
  GROUP BY am.CUST_ID, gd.GROUP_ID, am.START_DATE
  HAVING count(am.ATTRIBUTE_ID) = max(gc.ATTR_COUNT)
   ) src
    ON gm.GROUP_ID = src.GROUP_ID
       AND gm.CUST_ID = src.CUST_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
     THEN -- create association in GROUP_MAP
     INSERT(CUST_ID,
           GROUP_ID,
           FROM_DATE) VALUES
                         (src.CUST_ID, src.GROUP_ID, src.START_DATE);
```

Comment: I just used the setup code from @KamranFarzami to test this, and it doesn't work (was hasty to start with), and I don't have time to work on it now. I'll check back later.

Comment: Fixed and tested the code. I think it does what you are looking for.

Comment: This looks like its working so far.  I am confused a little bit about the syntax.  Why do we need to coalesce here: `coalesce(am.VALUE, '') = coalesce(gd.VALUE, '')`?

Comment: @Ted the sample data you showed has null values, so in order to match those we coalesce them to an empty non-null value. Take out the coalesce and see the difference - maybe I misunderstand your requirements so go with whatever works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly this should do it:

Please note I have used `GETDATE()` as I do not have the field [START_DATE] but you will need to substitute this within the code

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE #ATTRIBUTE_MAP(CUST_ID      INT,
                       ATTRIBUTE_ID INT,
                       VALUE        VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO #ATTRIBUTE_MAP
VALUES
      (50, 1, 'New York'),
      (50, 2, NULL);

CREATE TABLE #GROUP_DEFINITIONS(GROUP_ID    INT,
                          ATTRIBUTE_1 INT,
                          VALUE_1     VARCHAR(20),
                          ATTRIBUTE_2 INT,
                          VALUE_2     VARCHAR(20),
                          ATTRIBUTE_3 INT,
                          VALUE_3     VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO #GROUP_DEFINITIONS
VALUES
      (10, 1, 'New York', 2, NULL, NULL, NULL),
      (20, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

CREATE TABLE #GROUP_MAP(CUST_ID     INT,
                    GROUP_ID    INT,
                    [FROM_DATE] DATE);
```

QUERY:

```
MERGE #GROUP_MAP gm
USING
    (SELECT DISTINCT
           am.CUST_ID,
           CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS [START_DATE], --<-- you will need to change this
           gd.GROUP_ID
     FROM   #ATTRIBUTE_MAP am
           INNER JOIN
                   (
                   SELECT GROUP_ID,
                        ATTRIBUTE_1 AS ATTRIBUTE_ID,
                        VALUE_1
                   FROM     #GROUP_DEFINITIONS
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT GROUP_ID,
                        ATTRIBUTE_2,
                        VALUE_2
                   FROM     #GROUP_DEFINITIONS
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT GROUP_ID,
                        ATTRIBUTE_3,
                        VALUE_3
                   FROM   #GROUP_DEFINITIONS) gd ON am.ATTRIBUTE_ID = gd.ATTRIBUTE_ID) src
    ON gm.GROUP_ID = src.GROUP_ID
       AND gm.CUST_ID = src.CUST_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
     THEN -- create association in GROUP_MAP
     INSERT(CUST_ID,
           GROUP_ID,
           FROM_DATE) VALUES
                         (src.CUST_ID, src.GROUP_ID, src.START_DATE);
```

VERIFY RESULT:

```
SELECT CUST_ID , GROUP_ID , FROM_DATE
FROM   #GROUP_MAP;
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but to me it looks like this will incorrectly match a customer and group if some but not all of the attributes match. Your sample data does not have this scenario.

Comment: @radshop could you please complete the following and comment it back to me and I will test the scenario that you speak of:

INSERT INTO #GROUP_DEFINITIONS
VALUES
   (<value>, <value>, <value>, <value>, <value>, <value>, <value>)

Comment: INSERT INTO #GROUP_DEFINITIONS VALUES (30, 1, 'New York', 5, 'Bakery', NULL, NULL)

Comment: I see what you mean, but in a sense it is still correct as we also have Attribute_1 = 1 and Value_1 = 'New York' within that group.